# when map value type is Set, why need to re-assign if I modified the value?

Tags: swift

Here is my Swift code:

```
var myMap = [String: Set<String>]()

myMap["key"] = Set<String>()

var mySet = myMap["key"]

mySet?.insert("value")

//myMap["key"] = mySet

print("count:", myMap["key"]!.count)
```

output:

```
map.count: 0
```

but if uncomment the 5th line, will output:

```
map.count: 1
```

Why I need to assign `mySet` to `map["key"]` again? Is `mySet` not a reference type?

Comment: I believe set is a struct type and struct types are assign-by-copy, not -reference. But I'm having trouble quickly finding either of those explicitly in the Swift book.

Answer (score 3):

The swift `Set` type is a struct, meaning it conforms to value semantics. Types that behave with value semantics, as opposed to reference semantics, are always copied when attaining a reference to them, you can never reference the same value type from two different references. In your case, this means that `var mySet = myMap["key"]` creates a *copy* of the set in your map, not a reference to the set in your map. This means that you have to reassign the modified set back into the map for the change to reflect there.

Check out this swift blog entry from Apple explaining value semantics: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

Edit: As Nate noted in the comments, Swift doesn't actually create a new copy until the value type is modified, allowing the runtime to share references to value types as long as they aren't mutated, which is a nice optimization.

Comment:  One added note: the copy only happens on mutation, so an assignment like `var mySet = myMap["key"]` doesn't trigger a copy, but the insertion in the very next line does.